# add expired headers For google map API

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, yslow

I add `google map` in my `PHP` website. Now, I check My page using `Yslow` and i see in `add expired headers` :

`There are 17 static components without a far-future expiration date.`

Files Is:

```
(2014/4/25) http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?...
(2014/4/24) http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/9/%7Bcommon,map,util,marker%7D.js
(2014/4/23) http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/9/%7Binfowindow%7D.js
(2014/4/23) http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/9/%7Bonion%7D.js
(2014/4/23) http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/9/%7Bcontrols%7D.js
(1990/1/1) http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?...
(2014/4/23) http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/9/%7Bstats%7D.js
(1990/1/1) http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?...
(2014/4/25) http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?...
(2014/4/25) http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/9/main.js
(2014/4/25) http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur
(2014/4/25) http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_white2.png
(2014/4/25) http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt3.png
(2014/4/25) http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/cb_scout2.png
(2014/4/25) http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/arrow-down.png
(2014/4/25) http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png
```

How do i can add expired date for google map?!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the expiration date and cache settings for components loaded from other services like Google; you can only really improve that for components that you control (i.e. from your servers).

In this case I suggest taking a step back from the YSlow measurement/grade, and see if your app is fast enough from a user's viewpoint. If it's not, there may be other best practices for using the Google Maps API that you could implement.